# URL Encoding Causing problems iOS

Tags: iphone, encoding

So I'm trying to encode a multiline string and send over HTTP to the server, I am encoding this string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
     printf(\"Code Cabana!\");
     return 0;
}
```

and when I `NSLog` it I get this:

`151657384nclude23Cstdio.h3.825303E-2990X1.242D78P-1047220220220220220220220220220220220220                   0nt2ain(void)27B0X1.16BC009216BCP-877220220220220220220220220220220220220220220            0xe7fe00rintf(硨ode⭸abana!2;2202202202202202202202202202202202202202202eturn222022022022022022022022022022022022020A15203843`

I'm using this code to encode it:

```
NSString *urlCode = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#include <stdio.h>\n int main(void){\nprintf(\"Code Cabana!\");return 0;\n}"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: How did you `NSLog` `urlCode`? Did the server return an error?

Comment: I'm using `NSLog(urlCode);` The server sends it to a compiler which fails due to because `"` is encoded as `\`

Comment: Can you post the output of `NSLog(@"%@", urlCode);`? This is the proper way to log `urlCode`.

Comment: Don't use -stringWithFormat: if the string is not a format string.

Comment: True, you could just use a literal, but doesn't "any number of arguments" for a variable-length argument list also mean zero by definition? I couldn't find a conclusive answer in K&R, only that variadic functions must have at least one named parameter. That is satisfied by the definition of `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `NSLog(urlCode)`, use `NSLog(@"%@", urlCode)` like you should.

When you do that, your C source, URL-encoded in UTF-8, looks like this:

```
%23include%20%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%20int%20main(void)%7B%0Aprintf(%22Code%20Cabana!%22);return%200;%0A%7D
```

which is probably what you are after.

May I just say that there are huge security implications in sending C source code over the wire to a compiler, unless you never execute the compiled code.

As for the compiler failing, %22 is the straight quote `"`, so the other quote could be a copy-paste from a "smart" editor at your end.